# Footer text on page incorrectly displaying footer text from different page

Tags: errors, header-footer, footer

I am typesetting a book and have encountered what appears to be a bug in the footer on the book's final page. All footers in the book are correct except the last footer, which displays the correct page number but shows text from the footer of a page appearing 156 pages earlier in the book. I have no idea how to correct this. I have typeset 4 other books and have never encountered a similar problem with a header or footer.

Here is the code I am using to typeset the book. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,twoside,onecolumn,openany,final,showtrims]{memoir}

\setstocksize{9in}{7in}

\settrimmedsize{9in}{7in}{*}
\showtrimsoff

\settypeblocksize{7in}{4.6in}{*}

\setlrmargins{0.95in}{*}{*}

\setulmargins{0.75in}{*}{*}

\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{3\onelineskip}

\setheaderspaces{*}{0.2in}{*}

\setmarginnotes{0.3in}{0.8in}{0.05in}
\marginparmargin{outer}
\let\oldmarginpar\marginpar
\renewcommand\marginpar [2] []
{%
     \oldmarginpar{\mpjustification #2}}

\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{1.8em}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0em}
\footmarkstyle{#1\hfill}
\setfootins{0.3in}{}

\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=1000
\raggedbottom

\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{cjhebrew}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{plain}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{\thepage}

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{tipa}

\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do\h\do\w\do\x\do\a\do\//\do\b\do\n\do\_}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl}
```

Comment: There is not enough information. You must make a minimal but complete example that we can run ourselves, that shows the behaviour, otherwise we have no means to diagnose the problem correctly. But one thing you could look at is if the last part of your book uses some kind of group, e.g. `\begin{xxx} ... \end{xxx}` with a different page style inside the group. That could explain the problem. In that case a \clearpage` before the `\end{xxx}` could solve the problem.

Comment: While you are loading fancyhdr, you never set `\pagestyle{fancy}`.  Instead you are using memoir peculiar commands.  Or do you just want the line below the header?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Your comments spurred me to read more closely the fancyhdr manual and also to take a closer look at my code. I found a stray  }  in my code that caused the problem. My final three lines of code were:                                                     
}

\cleardoublepage

\end{document}

Comment: Simply deleting the stray  }  solved the problem. It does seem odd, however, that the  }  in the third to last line of the book's code somehow called up a footer from 150 pages earlier.